# Hiding information in the database from the view. - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table right now that displays a bunch of attributes of the User. Here is my problem. Each person has the ability to sign up to a group but in some edge cases a person can get in the table without being signed up to a group. for the sake of clarity for the users reading the table I'd like to simply hide each person that is not signed up to a group from the table. This is a bit more tricky than I anticipated. Ill show some code and a screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

as you can see if a person has no group don't display in table.

Im trying to make a method and call it on the controller rendering the table. The Person and Group are two different models with an association of HABTM. How do I say "if person has no groups don't display in table" in ruby?

```
def index
 @people = Person.order(sort_column => sort_direction)
 @groups = Group.all
end
```

This is the controller that is making the table

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable 'phone_number', 'Phone Number'%></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'subscribed', 'Subscribed'%></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'city' %></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'state' %></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'zip' %></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'country' %></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'created_at', "Joined" %></th>
    <th>Groups</th>

  </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @people.each do |person| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= person.phone_number %></td>
        <td><%= person.subscribed? ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
        <td><%= person.city %></td>
        <td><%= person.state %></td>
        <td><%= person.zip %></td>
        <td><%= person.country %></td>
        <td><%= time_ago_in_words person.created_at %> ago</td>
        <td><%= person.groups.order(:id).pluck(:name).to_sentence %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

group model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :people
 has_and_belongs_to_many :messages
end
```

perons model

```
 class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deliveries
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
```

Comment: can you show us your view (where you loop through people - I'm guessing?)?

Comment: If you have any association between group and person, can u show that also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These options are O(n^2) and pull in quite a bit into memory so as long as you're ok with that, these are easy to implement:

You have two options, one for your view:

```
<% @people.each do |person| %>
  <% next if person.groups.blank? %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= person.phone_number %></td>
    <td><%= person.subscribed? ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
    <td><%= person.city %></td>
    <td><%= person.state %></td>
    <td><%= person.zip %></td>
    <td><%= person.country %></td>
    <td><%= time_ago_in_words person.created_at %> ago</td>
    <td><%= person.groups.order(:id).pluck(:name).to_sentence %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Or you could filter in your controller:

```
@people = Person.order(sort_column => sort_direction).to_a.keep_if { |person| person.groups.present? }
```

Comment: Thanks the one in view works but I'd like to filter it  to the controller. But when I try that one you suggested it gives me an error "keep_if" is not defined?